# Can't copy file to usb

Tags: 14.04, usb, usb-drive

I can not copy a file to a USB flash drive (tested with two Transcend flash drives). I tried to copy using Nautilus, Thunar and terminal cp. After copying the file is displayed on the flash drive, but if you insert it into another computer or put out and put it back - it does not exist.

Comment: Any file in general or a specific file? If second is true, what kind of file?

Comment: Sorry if it's a stupid question, but are you sure there's no problem in the USB it's self ?

Comment: @the_Seppi all files. Serphiroth,  I used it in Windowse they worked fine.

Comment: How is the USB pendrive mounted? Read-only with a union filesystem?

Comment: I try to set chmod 777, but nothing happen. File System is NTFS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you unmount the USB drive before removing it? In Unix systems it's important to unmount removables otherwise the changes will not be written to it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a permission issue. Either you mounted it in read only or you have got the file in some wrong permission. Did you try viewing hidden files on the other computer? I would suggest transfering your files too a windows to see if the files arent your probleme.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

On a usb device I had already copied files to, the next time I tried I got error messages about input output errors.  What I found was that the folder I had created on the usb had become corrupted.  The best I can figure is that I had removed the device before closing the application ( in this case Krusader) I had used to copy the files.

My answer was to delete that folder, create a new one, and copy my files.  Just make sure to close all involved applications before removing the device.  That's what solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

unmount it in disks (accessories) mount it back in disks    (accessories) navigate in the file explorer to 'File System > Media >    Ubuntu' right click on your USB device search for and click 'Open As    Administrator'

Voila!

Comment: Please improve the layout and presentation of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well for me in 2023 the solution  that I found is: Open "Disk management utility for GNOME". Select USB and apply "Repair Filesystem" (you can run after "Check File system")

Sometime the issue happend when you had previously open the USB on Windows OS